# How do you exclude a property?

Tags: json, object, key, jq

I have the following dataset:

```
[
  {
    "py/object": "bit.ast.Node",
    "_children": [
      {
        "py/object": "bit.ast.Node",
        "_children": [
          "main",
          {
            "py/object": "bit.ast.Node",
            "_children": [
              "args",
              {
                "py/object": "bit.ast.Node",
                "_children": [
                  {
                    "py/object": "bit.ast.Node",
                    "_children": [
                      "str"
                    ],
                    "source_column": 2,
                    "source_filename": "tests/fixture/hello.b",
                    "source_line": 1,
                    "tag": "type-named"
                  }
                ],
                "base": {
                  "py/id": 10
                },
                "source_column": 2,
                "source_filename": "tests/fixture/hello.b",
                "source_line": 1,
                "tag": "type",
                "type": "array"
              }
            ],
```

(and so on...)

How do I get `jq` to exclude the `_children` property from all objects that have it? What about all properties that start with `_`?

None of the following seem to work:

```
jq 'map(del (._children))'
jq 'map(if has("_children") then del (._children) end)'
jq 'del(._children)'
jq 'del(.[]._children)'
jq 'del(.[]|._children)'
```

I keep getting an error similar to:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "_children"
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* sample of JSON that can be used as input.

Comment: @chepner What I have is more than sufficient for my use case.

Comment: @Qix - Without seeing more of the input, it is difficult to pinpoint the reasons for the errors you are reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exclude the _children property from all objects that have it

If your jq has `walk/1` then you could:

```
walk( if type == "object" then del(._children) else . end )
```

If not, first include its jq definition (readily googleable) e.g. in ~/.jq

> What about all properties that start with _ ?

For this, you could also use `walk/1`. For clarity and maintainability, it would make sense to define a helper function:

```
def deleteall(f): with_entries(select(.key | f | not ));
```

Which you'd invoke as: deleteall( startswith("_") )